# Apache Camel with 2 GET operations (Parameter and QueryParams)

Tags: java, get, apache-camel, quarkus

I am new with Camel in Quarkus and I am working on an API that has two GET Methods with a difference in the parameters sent, one with a specific parameter that is passed and another through QueryParam

Example:

- https://localhost:8084/userProfile/v3.6/users/{userid} ---> UniqueParame
- https://localhost:8084/userProfile/v3.6/users?identity1&identity2 --> QueryParam

I am configuring the routes in my ResRoute in the following way, however, it is giving me an error:

```
    rest("userProfile/v3.6/")
            .get("/users/{user_id}").to("direct:/{user_id}")
                .outType(UserProfile.class)
                .param().name("UserProfile").type(body).description("parametro de salida").required(true)
                .endParam()
                .to("direct:userIdParam");

    rest("userProfile/v3.6/")
            .get("/users?").to("direct:/users?")
            .outType(UserProfile.class)
            .param().name("UserProfile").type(body).description("parametro de salida").required(true)
            .endParam()
            .to("direct:usersQueryParam");
```

The error it gives me is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid u
rl: /userProfile/v3.6/users/userProfile/v3.6/users?identity=+584242222222. If you are forwarding/bridging http endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint option on the endpoint: https://10.162.128.94:30000/api/findCustomerDocumentBySubscriberId?bridgeEndpoint=false
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.createMethod(HttpProducer.java:643)
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:162)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:172)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:392)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$PipelineTask.run(Pipeline.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:181)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:165)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:392)
        at org.apache.camel.component.platform.http.vertx.VertxPlatformHttpConsumer.lambda$handleRequest$2(VertxPlatformHttpConsumer.java:201)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$null$0(ContextBase.java:137)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextBase.java:135)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

What have I configured incorrectly that is why I get this error?

Comment: From the stack trace it seems like you are trying to produce to an HTTP endpoint but have not specified either a host or scheme in the URL.